# Loops and .json parsing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm having trouble understanding a few things when it comes to loops and searching through a .json. I want to get the .json from a website then retrieve 25 items from ['body']'s then restart on a new .json page with new ['body']'s and retrieve those also. Finally, send the all data to a .txt file.
Here's my code

```
import json
import requests

#Settings
user_id = 29851266
page_num= 1
#Finds user data
max_p_f = requests.get('http://someforum/users/'+str(user_id)+'/posts.json?page='+str(page_num))
json_string = max_p_f.text
obj = json.loads(json_string)
max_page = obj['meta']['max_page']
current_page = obj['meta']['page']  
posts_count = obj['meta']['posts_count']
username = obj['users'][0]['username']
count = 0
start_page = 1

while page_num <= max_page:
    requests.get('http://www.someforum/users/'+str(user_id)+'/posts.json?page='+str(page_num))
    page_num += 1
print("Page "+str(start_page + 1)+ " complete")
    for x in range(0, 25):
        data = obj['posts'][x]['body']
        file = open(username+"_postdata.txt", 'a')
        file.write("\n =============="+str(count)+"==================\n")
        file.write(data)
        count += 1
        file.close()
```

I want the code to give me the 25 ['body'] values from the .json on the first page. Then go to a the second page a retrieve the new 25 ['body'] values. I am having trouble because when the values are written to the text file it only shows the first 25 ['body'] values and repeats those some 25 values until the while is fulfilled.

Comment: I'm surprised you are getting the data from the first page since you are not saving the `requests` response. Are you saving it into `obj`? can you manually access the `json` data in each of the new URLs (pages after the `start_page`) through a browser to ensure the new `json` page is accessible?

Comment: Yes, each new page is accessible. Also saving it into obj.

Comment: It seems like there are some errors in your code - where does `obj` get its value? When do you convert the object returned by `requests` from raw json into a dict?

Comment: You're also swapping `username` for `user_id` at different lines.

Comment: Can you describe both the expected and actual behaviour and how they differ?

Comment: Added the expectations and behaviors

Comment: tell me, on what line do you change `obj` **inside the loop**? (hint hint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using the native `.json()` for requests instead of converting it from text to json so it would be:

`requests.get('http://www.someforum/users/'+str(user_id)+'/posts.json?page='+str(page_num)).json()`

Also you're just using a request string in the loop, you're not actually saving the new obj with the new page number inside the loop

so outside your loop:

`max_p_f = 'http://someforum/users/'+str(user_id)+'/posts.json?page='`

and inside your loop it should be :

`obj = requests.get(max_p_f +str(page_num)).json()`

Here is a sample snippet, how I would do something very similar:

```
base_url = 'http://somewebsite/bunchofbjectsonapage.json?page=' 
max_page = 3
current_page = 0
while current_page <= max_page:
    current_page = current_page + 1
    obj = requests.get(base_url + str(current_page)).json()
    for item in obj:
        name = item['company_name']
        cat = item['category']
        print([name,cat])
```

[image]